# Estadisticas de elecciones primarias

Tags: discusión, elecciones, estadísticas

Ahora que hemos pasado por las elecciones primarias del sitio StackOverflow en Español, me doy cuenta que esta es una comunidad activa y participativa.

Me gustaría obtener datos estadísticos básicos de las elecciones primarias para darme una idea de la calidad de las votaciones y de la opinión en general de la comunidad de StackOverflow en español.

¿Que datos estadísticos se pueden obtener de estas elecciones primarias y de la comunidad de SOes en relación a este tema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Según la página de elecciones primarias disponible para todos los usuarios con reputacion suficiente para votar, la información ofrecida es la siguiente:

---

### **Comunidad**

```
+--------------------------+-----+
| Total de votos           | 855 |
+--------------------------+-----+
| Total de votos positivos | 692 |
+--------------------------+-----+
| Total de votos negativos | 163 |
+--------------------------+-----+
```

---

### **Candidatos**

A continuación algunos datos estadisticos de cada candidato en relación al total de votos.

1. Relación de votos positivos individuales con total de votos positivos emitidos por la comunidad
2. Relación de votos negativos individuales con total de votos negativos emitidos por la comunidad
3. Relación de votos totales individuales con total de votos totales emitidos por la comunidad
4. Relación de votos negativos individuales con total de votos individuales (esto es, que porcentaje de votos negativos recibí como candidato individualmente, es decir, cuantos votos negativos negativos atraje para mi mismo.)

```
+----+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    | Nombre         |   1    |    2   |   3    |   4    |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1  | Alvaro Montoro | 26.01% |  3.68% | 21.75% |  3.22% |
| 2  | Jorgesys       | 15.31% | 10.42% | 14.38% | 13.82% |
| 3  | lois6b         | 14.45% |  3.68% | 12.39% |  5.66% |
| 4  | fredyfx        | 10.69% |  7.36% | 10.05% | 13.95% |
| 5  | gbianchi       |  7.51% |  6.13% |  7.25% | 16.12% |
| 6  | Ivan Botero    |  6.50% |  7.36% |  6.66% | 21.05% |
| 7  | Carlos Muñoz   |  6.21% |  7.36% |  6.43% | 21.81% |
| 8  | ArtEze         |  3.75% | 14.11% |  5.73% | 46.93% |
| 9  | Paul Vargas    |  3.61% | 15.33% |  5.84% | 50.00% |
| 10 | toledano       |  3.32% | 11.65% |  4.91% | 45.23% |
| 11 | Joel Ibaceta   |  2.60% | 12.88% |  4.56% | 53.84% |
+----+----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
     |          Total | 99.96% | 99.96% | 99.95% |  N.A.  |
     +----------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

### Otros datos interesantes de elecciones primarias:

- Intente buscar en [Data StackExchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/queries?order_by=recent&q=primary+election) pero no encontre una forma de ver cuantos usuarios habian votado en las elecciones primarias. Voy a aproximar unos 170 usuarios diferentes (que era la cantidad de usuarios diferentes que votaron en la fase final al 31 de julio de 2017). Eso nos da como resultado, 5 votos por persona, de media. (**Gracias** a [Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/301/jose-antonio-dura-olmos) que me hizo ver que estaba en un error y que el dato que tenia no era de las elecciones primarias.) Entonces, los siguientes datos tambien son aproximados.
- En este año, hubo **[542 usuarios](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/703842/active-users-able-to-vote-and-active-since-first-day-of-primary-election)** que visitaron el sitio del 24 de julio de 2017 en adelante (activos en elecciones primarias) y que tenian suficiente reputación para votar. Eso significa que aprox. 31% de estos usuarios participaron en las elecciones primarias.
- En total, tenemos [878 usuarios con suficiente reputacion](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/703846) para
  votar. Eso significa que aprox. 61% de estos usuarios visitaron las
  elecciones primarias y aprox. 19% de estos usuarios votaron.

---

### Mi conclusión:

Estamos bien. Que el 19% de nuestros usuarios con capacidad de hacerlo votarán, me parece bien. Considerando que el sitio es bastante nuevo, y que es nuestra primera eleccion, y que, además de todo esto, existan muchas personas de habla hispana aun en SO, definitivamente **estamos bien**, y veo que las personas aqui presentes tenemos interés en el sitio. Estoy seguro que en las próximas elecciones lo haremos mucho mejor y que el numero de usuarios activos y con capacidad de votar seguirá creciendo. ¡Larga vida a SOes!

Comment: Tu realizaste la agregación de los datos ¿verdad? Me parece que deberías mencionarlo.

Comment: En algunos paises es ilegal publicar estadísticas sobre elecciones mientras estas están en marcha, en España por ejemplo. Esto no aplica a elecciones privadas, como es este caso, pero igualmente habría sido más elegante esperar a que finalizasen las elecciones.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, pero ya finalizaron, no? Estas son de las primarias, de las cuales, por supuesto, ya sabemos los resultados.

Comment: Gracias @Kenny, excelente información.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos no se porque ya no puedo ver tu comentario, pero gracias. Tenias toda la razon y yo estaba equivocado. El dato de los usuario que han votado era de la fase final (que no ha terminado aun) y yo pense que era de la fase primaria. Reconozco mi error y he editado la informacion para que sea un numero cercano a eso, que por seguro asi fue (ya que no tengo idea como ver el numero real). Un +1 para vos.

Comment: Un informe muy completo, gracias !!