# ¿Me permitirían ser el 4.º moderador?

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Buenas noches estimada comunidad, espero se encuentren bien, llevo tiempo pensando si debería escribir o no esta pregunta y finalmente he decidido lanzarla para saber vuestras opiniones.

Primero lo primero, una presentación de quien escribe:

Me llamo Fredy, estoy en el sitio de Stack Overflow versión hispana (SOes) desde los inicios prácticamente, he tenido la oportunidad de ser moderador [`pro témpore`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1970/822) y fue una experiencia maravillosa porque pude retribuir con creces a la red todo aquello que aprendí de manera libre, hice lo mejor que pude en aquel entonces para mantener nuestro sitio ordenado y con la buena vibra. En [las elecciones oficiales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2600/822), quedé en el olimpo porque el sistema de votación eliminó hasta el 5.º lugar y pasaron los 3 primeros con el rol de moderación (véase el [desglose de los resultados](https://www.opavote.com/results/5714798125776896)).

Me encuentran generalmente en las etiquetas de `C#`, `ASP.Net MVC`, `JavaScript` y `jQuery`, hice un [workshop maratónico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY) de 4 horas 4 minutos y 4 segundos para la comunidad, el tema fue ASP.net MVC 5 con Entity Framework y algo de JavaScript, donde traté en lo posible de explicar a detalle basado en las preguntas frecuentes que habían en aquel entonces.

Tengo el gusto de ser algo así como el encargado de dar las bienvenidas a los nuevos usuarios en la sala de chat de SOes lo cual es una tradición que ha evolucionado con el pasar del tiempo, de ser unas breves preguntas hasta llegar a ser un ritual mágico donde más integrantes que andan por la sala de chat colaboran con el tema, un asunto lleno de buena vibra para amenizar la iniciación de un nuevo en la sala buscando la integración y la armonía entre todos los usuarios.

Siempre me ha gustado guiar a los usuarios por el buen camino ninja, recomendando los clásicos enlaces de cómo preguntar y el tour especial para el mejor entendimiento del sitio.

Sé de la gran responsabilidad que existe en el rol de moderador y estoy dispuesto a ir con ello.

Somos una de las naciones digitales más grandes de Hispanoamérica, hay un crecimiento cada vez más rápido del sitio y más trabajo por hacer, me gustaría saber si me permiten colaborar nuevamente en esta aventura de la moderación.

Espero vuestras respuestas y veamos qué sucede, sea la respuesta afirmativa o negativa, estuve, estoy y estaré colaborando con el sitio dando siempre lo mejor de mi.

Con cariño, su hermano del código,

[@fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/822/fredyfx?tab=profile)

Que tengan buenas madrugadas.

Comment: pues si se puede votar, cuenta con mi apoyo

Comment: Gracias Alfredo :D Veamos qué sucede.

Comment: Fredy, sabes que cuentas con toda mi simpatía. Eres un usuario muy positivo y que efectivamente trata de dar todo para ayudar. Pero creo que te equivocas con este post. Tu sabes perfectamente cual es el proceso de elección de moderadores, y esta no es la forma. Cuando haya otro proceso electoral, si te presentas, puedes contar con mi voto. Pero este post no tiene mucho sentido, ya que no hay manera de que se te pueda elegir "a dedo" sin pasar por el proceso estipulado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo hermano ...!!!! Cuenta conmigo

Comment: Te vote negativo porque eres un usuario viejo y conoces las reglas y los requisitos para los nuevos moderadores

Comment: Hermano, en realidad **todos los usuarios de la comunidad Stackoverflow en español son el 4.º moderador**, si los miembros de la comunidad apoyan en las tareas de moderación, te aseguro que su ayuda es muy valiosa y en realidad contribuyen a moderar el sitio de una manera sana!.

Comment: @Jorgesys Pareciera que no quieres que haya más moderadores ♦. Punto y aparte de eso me parece muy bueno, que digo bueno, excelente, resaltar lo importante que es y promover la participación de los miembros de la comunidad en las tareas de moderación.

Comment: @Rubén respeto tu opinión si piensas que "no quiero que haya más moderadores" o si votas por "AMLO", es broma hehe, **no es mi decisión en realidad si se agrega un moderador o 10, en realidad lo único que aportaría es beneficio**. Pero es importante saber que necesitamos más participación en las colas de revisión y en reportes, hay usuarios que comúnmente apoyan en esta tarea pero somos muchos miembros de la comunidad que pudiéramos apoyar.

Comment: @Jorgesys no es lo que pienso, es lo que parece que expresa tu comentario previo. En cuanto hay que saber que se necesita más participación, que bueno que lo mencionas. En los últimos meses he participado muy poco en las cosas de revisión. Voy a procurar pasar mas por ahí.

Comment: @Rubén en realidad no todos tenemos el tiempo, es comprensible, simplemente un poquito de ayuda entre todos sería grandioso, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Mi nuevo mantra Un review al día da salud (a SOes) y alegría ;)

Comment: @Pikoh, gracias bro, justamente eso de "necesitar otro proceso electoral" para ser mod era algo que quería confirmar, en algún lado había leído que en caso la comunidad lo requiera, puede haber un nuevo mod.

Comment: Independiente de las reglas, si hay elecciones o no, sea lo que sea, contarías con mi voto indiscutiblemente, serías un muy buen moderador para el sitio, slaudos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo hermano :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lo siento pero **no estoy de acuerdo**.

Estoy absolutamente de acuerdo en que eres una persona que da buen ambiente al sitio y esto te hace fundamental. Sin embargo, ser moderador no es eso: como bien sabes porque lo fuiste, se trata de ser el encargado de vigilar que no haya ventanas rotas, trabajar desde detrás para que todo sea armónico, así como actuar de forma quirúrgica cuando algo o alguien falla.

Las virtudes que explicas te hacen, como dije antes, un usuario muy útil para la comunidad, generando buen ambiente y ayudando a incorporar a nuevos usuarios. A mí me sorprende que se considere que esta es la tarea de los moderadores, y me sorprende que sea una parte importante del tiempo que dedican los moderadores actuales al sitio. Esta tarea es bueno que la hagan, pero no es necesario tener un diamante para hacerla.
Creo que el moderador debe estar pendiente de qué tendencias tiene el sitio, cómo encauzarlas, qué puede necesitar del CM y, por tanto, estar en contacto constante y directo con los CM y los moderadores de otros sitios para recabar posibilidades de mejora para el sitio.

Además, y probablemente más importante, [ya estamos graduados](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/04/20/buenas-noticias-para-mayo-2017/), por lo que la elección de moderadores ya no es a dedo, sino a través de elecciones. Recientemente pregunté sobre la necesidad de nuevos moderadores y el CM [indicó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3631/83) que no hace falta. Si crees que sí hacen falta, es cuestión de argumentarlo aquí en Meta y proponer elecciones. Yo creo que sí que iría bien. Viendo cómo te fue en las elecciones anteriores, así como que fuiste el [2.º más popular en la precandidatura (empatado)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2322/83) tienes muchos números de ser elegido :)

Finalmente, y como detalle no importante pero tal vez relevante, me sorprendió que en las [estadísticas de tu época de moderador](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2435/83) se indicara que los otros moderadores habían enviado decenas de mensajes privados a usuarios, mientras que tú ninguno. Puede que fuera un cúmulo de circunstancias, pero la de los mensajes es una herramienta útil en muchos casos, por lo que tal vez la debiste utilizar (más).

Comment: Tengo que estar totalmente de acuerdo contigo. En un sitio graduado como este, el proceso de selección de moderadores está claramente marcado, y se basa en un proceso electoral bien definido.

Comment: Gracias bro, en algún lado había leído que podría haber un nuevo mod en caso se requiera y bueno, con todo el crecimiento del sitio, pensé que sería "adecuado" realizar esta pregunta. Por cierto, eso de los mensajes fue algo que desconocía.

Answer (score 5):

Te felicito por hacer una declaración de interés acerca de ser moderador ♦.

Me parece que harías una muy buena labor punto y aparte de que para ser embajador / evangelista de SOes no es necesario tener el ♦ así como tampoco para continuar dando la bienvenida y animando el chat.

Temo que tu declaración no sea bien recibida pues como no somos muy dados a hacer [preguntas retóricas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogaci%C3%B3n_ret%C3%B3rica) particularmente en el título de la preguntas de Meta será interpretada literalmente. Si no fuera esta tu intención te sugiero agregar alguna nota o comentario al respecto.

[AMLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9s_Manuel_L%C3%B3pez_Obrador) estuvo en campaña varios lustros, y mira, ya es Presidente Electo de México :)

Serenidad, paciencia y sigue con todo el poder 2.0.

Comment: Que otra forma hay de interpretar dicho titulo???

Comment: @CristianS9 Cómo dIje en la primera línea, como una declaración de interés en ser moderador. P.D. Las preguntas retóricas son formas de expresar algo que aunque  lleva signos de interrogación no se espera respuesta de esto. (agregué unos enlaces a mi respuesta).

Comment: te pregunto porque teniendo en cuenta el contexto, no me imagino que otro sentido puede llegar a tener esta pregunta que el literal

Comment: @CristianS9 ¿ni siquiera te lo imaginas luego de leer mi comentario previo?

Comment: Gracias por las felicitaciones bro! Precisamente ese título de manera retórica de un `sí` o un `no` es lo que necesito para realizar una autoevaluación, hay cosas de las que quiero estar seguro, tales como la elección abierta, y no es que quisiera ser elegido "a dedo", lo cual no me parece correcto dicho sea de paso. Como dije al final: `Sea la respuesta afirmativa o negativa, estuve, estoy y estaré colaborando con el sitio dando siempre lo mejor de mi.`, seguimos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: @fredyfx ^^^ Esa es la actitud que te marca como miembro lustrante. No necesitas tener un diamante para contribuir de manera impactante, tal y como se ha dicho.  Si en un momento se requieren otras elecciones, se que estarás en los últimos lugares...si es que no te eligen de inmediato. ¡Gracias por tu apoyo y por tu dedicación a nuestra gran comunidad!

Comment: @JuanM por curiosidad, ¿qué hay de erróneo en el punto de vista de mi respuesta?

Comment: @JuanM gracias hermano, de nada, lo hago con mucho cariño y con la mejor de las intenciones: enseñar y guiar. Somos la única industria donde compartiendo se llega más lejos y sitios como SOes incrementan esta visión. ¡Entre todos podemos lograr más! Un abrazote, saludos :D

Comment: @fedorqui No encuentro nada erróneo en tu respuesta. Estoy de acuerdo con lo mencionas.  Tienes razón sobre el proceso de nuestras elecciones y también en tu apreciación de nuestro amigo Fredyfx. Te agradezco por compartir tus pensamientos especialmente cuando lo haces con respeto y que puede ser algo recibido negativamente por otros.